# Get Eurostat data with both labels and codes

Tags: types, label, geocode

I am trying to get Eurostat data tables including both codes and labels (for variables and geographical entitities).

With the following scripts I get only codes (1) or only labels (2)

(1)
demo <- get_eurostat(id = "urb_cpop1",
type = "code")
(2)
demo <- get_eurostat(id = "urb_cpop1",
type = "label")